Variant: 1st check wins
This is a simple chess variant: Normal starting position, normal rules, except the first check wins. With the problem chess software Popeye, alas, you can verify that 1.Nc3 due to the "fork" threats already forces Black to run to the hills with its king, and its a check in 5 latest. Even 1.Na3 works, and so do 1.e4 or 1.e3.
Still, no White progress in the latter variant without a N. I thus switched to Chess 960 and swapped R and N on the queenside (NRBQKBNR). Popeye confirmed no +7 exists, and +8 would take at least a day to verify due to the high branching ratio.
Can someone try an analysis "by brain" instead, sort of an opening theory? Can Black hold, presumably by 1...e6? (If yes, this would be a fun chess variant in a youth group.) Using an engine, this might be relevant.

Popeye ran through, an +8 exists, and the variant (the wQ runs amok and Black can't leash it forever) rather suggests that even in other 960 positions the tempo advantage always decides. (I make a list as soon as I have more time.)
